# Nginx, turn off cache for a specific file

Tags: caching, nginx

```
location /static {
    alias /home/ubuntu/Documents/zibann/momsite/momsite/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    if ($uri ~* ".*config.js") {
       expires off;
    }

    if ($uri ~* ".*\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|svg)" ) {
       access_log off;
       expires 365d;
       add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

}
```

Hoping `config.js` would not get cached, but it does.
How can I exclude one file from being cached?

Comment: If you know the path of config.js, use a = location or a prefix location.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make a separate location block for config.js above the others.

```
location ~ config\.js {
    alias xyz;
    expires off;
}

location static etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all samples above, and in other pages. The only thing worked for me was this. My file was a PHP and a I had to create a complete copy of my last part of the configuration file. Maybe replacing **location ~ config.js** will work for you too.

```
location ~ player\.php {
        set $no_cache 1;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;   
            if (-f $request_filename) {
                # Only throw it at PHP-FPM if the file exists (prevents some PHP exploits)
                fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/run/php7-fpm.sock;
                #fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
            }         
}
```